# Почему slick slider добавляет слайдеры вниз?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

Как видите **8** блоков *4 снизу 4 сверху* все устроено флексбоксами.

Слайдер начинает свою работу при ширине меньше `768` пикселей (при ресайзе или при загрузке страницы ) [**CODEPEN ССЫЛКА ТУТ**](https://codepen.io/Onixia/pen/WJmPPR)

Проблема заключается в том что если его `touchpad`-ом или же другим способом  сменить то новый слайд добавляется вниз а иногда проста все изчезает и растет высота блока вот так  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А нужно чтобы было так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В настройках я ничего особенного не сделал все стандартно и стабильно

```
          centerMode: true, //режим чтобы поставить блоки по центру
          infinite: true, //бесконечная прокрутка
          prevArrow: false, //убрал стрелки
          nextArrow: false, //убрал стрелки
          speed: 200, //скорость 200
          slidesToShow: 1, // показать 1 элемент
          slidesToScroll:1 //менять по одному элементу
```

Или же  если кто нибудь предложит другое решение с использованием другова слайдера чтобы работал также я ответы принимаю.Главное чтобы работал

Очень хотел бы чтобы кто нибудь помог а то уже 4 ый день застрял на слайдере.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский спасибо тебе большое

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/vjMWzG?editors=0110  смотри ... не знаю какой баг вылезет

Comment: @МаксимЛенский крут .!а что ты поменял мне надо знать потому что у меня на локальном scss стоит в webpack-е и я не могу просто все копи пастить

Comment: смотри в самом низу css - вот эти параметры надо тебе изменить в scss

Comment: @МаксимЛенский напиши ответ приму :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы в стилях явно указали где то ширину слайдов и собственно по этому они не помещаются

Я с `!important` изменил в `@media` стили отдельного слайда

Измените ваши стили

```css
@media (max-width:768px) {
  .container-slick {
    max-width: 90% !important;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .projects_block .slide {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100% !important;
    margin: 0 -20px !important;
    outline: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width:555px) {
  .container-slick {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  .projects_block .slide {
    max-width: 95% !important;
    margin: 0 -30px !important;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: спасибо еще раз если бы не ты я бы копалсья еще дня три как минимум

Comment: мой маленький совет - начинай такие вещи в мобильной версииъ

Comment: возму в заметку